# selenium unit test not detecting form fields

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

I have a html file which gets form fields from a FlaskForm. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Xpress Products - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Xpress Products</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Xpress Products</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('xpress') }}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('storestock') }}">Stock</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('order') }}">Place Order</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('amend') }}">Amend Order</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('cancel') }}">Cancel Order</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('addproduct') }}">Add Products</a>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
          {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
              {% for category, message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                  {{ message }}
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endwith %}
          {% block content %}
    <div>
    <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="content-section">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Add new Product</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form.newproduct.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {{ form.newproduct(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-2'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form.pricepsmall.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {{ form.pricepsmall(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-2'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form.pricepmedium.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {{ form.pricepmedium(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}                       
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md-2'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{ form.priceplarge.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                {{ form.priceplarge(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}                       
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    {% endblock content %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am making a unit test using selenium. The code is:

```
class TestProductStore(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(60) 

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_form_addproduct(self):
        self.driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/addproduct')  

        newproduct_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name('form.newproduct')
        pricepsmall_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name('form.pricepsmall')
        pricepmedium_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name('form.pricepmedium')
        priceplarge_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name('form.priceplarge')

        # Populate inputs with dummy text
        newproduct_input.send_keys('Rich Blend Teabag Carton')
        pricepsmall_input.send_keys(15.0)
        pricepmedium_input.sendkeys(18.0)
        priceplarge_input.sendkeys(21.0)

        # Find submit button and submit form by sending an "Enter" keypress
        submit_button = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn-outline-info')+
        submit_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        admin_url = self.driver.current_url
        self.assertEqual(admin_url, 'http://localhost:5000/addproduct')

        theproduct = Products.objects.get(product_desc='Rich Blend Teabag Carton')
        self.assertEqual(theproduct.product_desc, 'Rich Blend Teabag Carton')
```

running the test throws the following error:

*selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="form.newproduct"]"}*

Could someone please guide me how to rephrase the code to enable detection of the form fields.
Help will be greatly appreciated.
Just to let you know, I also tried to find elements without the form prefix, like for example,

```
newproduct_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name('newproduct')
```

This also does not work

Tried to search by xpath:

```
newproduct_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="newproduct"]')
```

but still same error:
*selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="newproduct"]"}*

Comment: The link at the top of the duplicate gives you a lot of very good information to look through.  Most likely your issue is due to not waiting.  It's always good practice to use waits in your automation code because you can run into a timing issue with your code where the page isn't done loading, but your code is looking for an element and returning the error.  You can find some additional help on waits here:  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: I did apply a wait, even of up to 60 seconds. I do not think wait may be the issue. Can you please suggest something else. I have looked on the internet a lot for the solution. Regards.

Comment: I would need to see the complete html to be able to give a better answer.

Comment: The complete html attached now

Comment: Is it possible to give a link to this page?  As a suggestion to try, I would try to locate the elements through driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("fieldset div.form-group").  This should return a collection of the elements you're trying to find, but will most likely require additional drilling down to get the fields you're trying to interact with.